# Is there a button to go to saved jobs or favorites, with less than four entries?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

I might be missing it, there is a button labelled `"View all favorite jobs"`, which is displayed when there are more than four entries, or more than can be displayed in the `Favorites` right side widget, under `Saved searches`.

I notice that clicking the yellow star under jobs is the same as viewing the entry and clicking `Save` with the *blue* star. But they all go to the same Favorites, which is the same as `Saved jobs`, am I understanding the wording, or are there different places here that I'm missing?

Answer (score 3):

*Edit/Note*: I'm a developer on the team at Stack Overflow that works on this part of the product.

**Update**: As you pointed out, we were inconsistent in how we labeled "Favorite"/"Saved" jobs.  As of today (2019-09-30), they are called "Saved" jobs across the site.
[image]

---

For your first question:

> Is there a button to go to saved jobs or favorites, with less than four entries?

Currently, there is not a button or link to load the search results view with your favorite jobs if you have less than five. (Though, the URL of the `View all favorite jobs` will work in that case -- we just don't display it in the sidebar.)

For slightly more context:
The sidebar on the jobs search page will show your first four jobs which you've marked as a "favorite" (or fewer, if you don't have four).  If you have more than four, the `View all favorite jobs` link is displayed to load all your "favorite" jobs in the search results view.

As for the "Saved jobs" vs "Favorite job" naming: 
You are correct -- those are the same thing.  It looks like we're calling them "Favorite jobs" in some screens and "Saved jobs" in others.  I'll get this on our backlog to review and make it consistent across all the pages.